# How is it possible to avoid a mock runtime and use the actual runtime for testing?

Tags: runtime, testing, mock, configuration, unit-tests

I would like to avoid the most pallet config initialisation and just want to use the actual runtime configuration for the (unit) tests. This would simplify my mock process a lot. The only thing that comes into mind is to mock the balances.

So I need to implement `ExtBuilder`. The reason to take this approach is because I always need to copy stuff from my actual runtime to the mock, but in my case it's always the same configuration.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to have the `mock.rs` inside the runtime folder. Then you can just import all runtime parameters with `use crate::*;` inside the `mock.rs`.

Just found out that I can just use `Runtime` instead of `Test` as a generic to all instances of the test and mock. In addition to that, you need to create Accounts as actual accounts and not just numbers.

```rust
use sp_core::{sr25519, Pair, Public, H256};
use sp_runtime::traits::{IdentifyAccount, Verify};

type AccountPublic = <Signature as Verify>::Signer;

/// Helper function to generate a crypto pair from seed
pub fn get_from_seed<TPublic: Public>(seed: &str) -> <TPublic::Pair as Pair>::Public {
    TPublic::Pair::from_string(&format!("//{seed}"), None)
        .expect("static values are valid; qed")
        .public()
}

/// Helper function to generate an account ID from seed
pub fn get_account_id_from_seed<TPublic: Public>(seed: &str) -> AccountId
where
    AccountPublic: From<<TPublic::Pair as Pair>::Public>,
{
    AccountPublic::from(get_from_seed::<TPublic>(seed)).into_account()
}

pub fn alice() -> AccountId {
    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Alice")
}

pub fn bob() -> AccountId {
    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Bob")
}

pub fn charlie() -> AccountId {
    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Charlie")
}

pub fn dave() -> AccountId {
    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Dave")
}

pub fn eva() -> AccountId {
    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Eva")
}

pub fn fred() -> AccountId {
    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Fred")
}
```

You can leave the `ExtBuilder` as it is. It just builds the execution environment with the actual runtime as a charm!